# SSRS Date Parameter Validation

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**image description here:**
[image: image 1]

while am entering alphabates or numbers in dateparameter textbox in report then click viewreport. it shows an error occured processing report the value provided for report parameter fromdate  is not valid types. instead of above error i want to show my own label as please enter valid date like format MM/DD/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can do so but it is not recommended as you are touching web.config file of reporting extensions

1-Browse to Report Manager folder. For SSRS 2005, its typical location is DRIVE:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting Services\ReportManager, where x is the instance; for SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2008 R2, DRIVE:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SSRS\Reporting Services\ReportManager.

2-Make a copy of the existing Web.config as backup

3-Open Web.config in a text editor, or in Visual Studio to get Intellisense support

4-Under the section, locate the  section

5-Modify the existing section, or insert a new one, with the appropriate settings

6-Restart the Report Server
Below Link will help you. Let us know this help you or not.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/87989623-068f-4c45-84e9-d151635ac1b3/

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-error-handling-workbench/

Comment: there is no web.config only rdl file is there in ssrs report viewer

Comment: This is on server where your reporting service is hosted.

Comment: this will work only when you deploy your report on server either test or prod and will not work on preview mode.